# Pandas Dataframe: Find unique value from one column which has the largest number of unique values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, unique-values

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[99, 88, 88, 66, 66, 99, 66, 77, 77, 77, 66, 66, 99, 99], list('DAABBBBABCBDDD'), ['***','**','****','*','***','*','**','***','*','*','****','**','**','****']]).T
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3']
```

Assume that col1 are companies and col2 are products types. I am looking for the company with the largest number of different product types.

So I am looking for which unique value from col1 has the largest number of unique values in col2

I have tried the following:

```
df.groupby(['col1'])['col2'].nunique()
```

which returns:

```
col1
66    2
77    3
88    1
99    2
```

Now I would like to get the value from col1 with the highest value in col2. Which is:

```
77    3
```

I have tried

```
df.groupby(['col2'])['col1'].nunique().max()
```

However I only receive the max of unique values in col2

```
3
```

Instead, I would like to know both the max value from col2 and to which value in col1 this belongs. I.e.

```
 77    3
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know both the max value from col2 and to which value in col1 this belongs.

With your result, call both:

```
result = df.groupby(['col1'])['col2'].nunique()
result.idxmax()  # 77
result.max()  # 3
```

You could also convert it to a DataFrame before calling `.loc[lambda d: d.idxmax()]` but I don't know why you would want to do that.

Comment: better use `idx = result.idxmax() ; result[idx]` to avoid unnecessarily computing the max twice

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
grouped=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['col1'])['col2'].nunique()).reset_index()
grouped[grouped['col2'] == grouped["col2"].max()]
```